# what USB port does my laptop contain?

Tags: laptop, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a HP ENVY laptop 13-ah0xxx I brought about 2 years ago. As I'm now working from home I have attached an extra monitor to my laptop. The monitor has a HDMI cable which I use plug into a USD adapter which is plugged into my laptop as my laptop doesn't have a HDMI port.

I'm trying to find out what ports I actually have. I can see two USB A ports & one USB C port. However when I go device manager & expand Universal Serial Bus controllers I see the following,

```
Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)
USB Composite Device
USB Composite Device
USB Composite Device
USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
```

There is also a USB Connector Managers node which has,

```
UCM-UCSI ACPI Device
```

Is anyone able to explain how I can see 2 USB A & 1 USB C on my laptop yet have all the above listed. How can I determine if my USB are 3.0 or not etc?

Comment: The Type-C is a USB 3.0 port.  Device Manager is matching what ports actually exist

Comment: Go to this page and punch in your serial number for the laptop, then download any manual you need>>>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I determine if my USB are 3.0 or not etc?

Your USB ports are `3.2 Gen 1` (also called `USB 3.1 Gen 1`, `USB 3.0`):

> 1x USB Type-C 3.2 Gen 1 (5 Gbps)
>
> 1x USB Type-A 3.2 Gen 1 (5 Gbps)
>
> 1x USB Type-A 3.2 Gen 1 (5 Gbps)

Source: [HP Envy 13 2018 (13-ah0000) review – a classy business notebook](https://laptopmedia.com/review/hp-envy-13-13-ah0000-review-a-classy-business-notebook/#specs-sheet)

USB Naming:

> [image]

Source: [USB - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Naming_scheme)

If you are running Windows then you can [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/).

Here is an example screen shot of my USB actives devices:

> [image]

I am not affiliated with [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way; I am just an end user of their software.

Answer (score 3):

> Is anyone able to explain how I can see 2 USB A & 1 USB C on my laptop yet have all the above listed. How can I determine if my USB are 3.0 or not etc?

All of the USB ports are USB 3.2 Gen 1 according to the specifications I found for your device.

> The monitor has a HDMI cable which I use plug into a USD adapter which is plugged into my laptop as my laptop doesn't have a HDMI port.

While your device supports USB Type-C video out it sounds like the monitor is what’s incompatible with the setup.  You should make sure you have the current Intel display drivers installed.

Comment: To clarify, USB 3.2 gen 1 is literally the same thing as USB 3.1 gen 1 and USB 3.0. They're rebadging it every iteration.